# From the set $S=\{1,...,n\}$, count the number of ways to have $ab=cd$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

So I found an interesting pattern when looking at the number of zero divisors in a set of matrices, but proving that it works will involve solving the following

Say $S=\{1,...,n\}$ for some positive integer $n$.

How many $4$-tuples $(a,b,c,d)$ of elements of $S$ are there with$\,\;a\le b,\;c\le d,\;a < c\;\,$such that $ab=cd\,$?

For example, say $S=\{1,...,8\}$.

Then we have
\begin{align*}
1 \times 4 &= 2 \times 2\\[4pt]
1 \times 6 &= 2 \times 3\\[4pt]
1 \times 8 &= 2 \times 4\\[4pt]
2 \times 6 &= 3 \times 4\\[4pt]
2 \times 8 &= 4 \times 4\\[4pt]
3 \times 8 &= 4 \times 6\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so the count is $6$.

I believe there is some sort of general pattern for the count for any such set $S$, but I've been having trouble figuring it out.

Comment: how many are there without restrictions ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee The restriction would be the size of the set S being looked at. I guess what I'm looking for is some kind of function that would take in the size of the set S and output the number of such expressions discussed in the post.

Comment: Any composite number can be so written as $ab = 1*ab = a*b$.

Comment: @quasi That's my bad.  0 wouldn't need to included in the set.  It's there because for the larger problem on working on, it's important - but not for this question

Comment: Would you formulate the question in a unique (and clear) way?

Comment: Wlod AA:$\;$See the edited version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each positive integer $n$, let $f(n)$ be the number of $4$-tuples $(a,b,c,d)$ of integers such that

- $1\le a \le b\le n$$\\[4pt]$

  $a < c \le d\le n$$\\[4pt]$

  $ab=cd$

Your preferred goal is to find a closed-form expression for $f(n)$.

My sense is that's probably not possible, however, using an auxiliary function $g(n)$ expressible as a summation, we can get a recursion . . .

For each positive integer $n$, let $g(n)$ be the number of pairs $(a,b)$ of integers such that

- $1 < a \le b < n$$\\[4pt]$

  $n{\,\mid\,}ab$

Then we have the recursion
$$
f(n)=
\begin{cases}
0&\;\;\;\text{if}\;n=1\\[4pt]
f(n-1)+g(n)&\;\;\;\text{if}\;n > 1\\
\end{cases}
$$
and where $g(n)$ can be computed via the summation
$$
g(n)
=
\sum_{a=1}^{n-1}
\left(
\gcd(a,n)
-
\left\lceil
\frac{a{\,\cdot}\gcd(a,n)}{n}
\right\rceil
\right)
$$
hence, $f(n)$ can be expressed as
$$
f(n)
=
\sum_{k=1}^n g(k)
=
\sum_{k=1}^n
\sum_{a=1}^{k-1}
\left(
\gcd(a,k)
-
\left\lceil
\frac{a{\,\cdot}\gcd(a,k)}{k}
\right\rceil
\right)
$$
Using the above, here are the results for $1\le n\le 16\,$:
\begin{array}
{c
|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|
}
\hline
n&
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16
\\ 
\hline
g(n)&
0&0&0&1&0&2&0&3&3&4&0&9&0&6&8&10
\\
\hline
f(n)&
0&0&0&1&1&3&3&6&9&13&13&22&22&28&36&46
\\
\hline
\end{array}

Some explanations . . .

$\bullet\;$Explanation for the recursion for $f(n)$ . . .

  Fix
  $n > 1$
  .
  Any $4$-tuple $(a,b,c,d)$ counted by $f(n-1)$ is a qualifying $4$-tuple for $f(n)$.

  The $4$-tuples $(a,b,c,d)$ for $f(n)$ that are not counted by $f(n-1)$ are those where one of $a,b,c,d$ is equal to $n$, which is what $g(n)$ counts.

  Thus $f(n)=f(n-1)+g(n)$.

$\bullet\;$Explanation for the summation for $g(n)$ . . .

  By the conditions on
  $a,b,c,d$
  , it's not possible for more than one of
  $a,b,c,d$
  to be equal to
  $n$
  .
  Thus, $g(n)$ counts the number of pairs $(a,b)$ with $1 \le a \le b\le n-1$ such that $n{\,\mid\,}ab$.

  Fix $a\in \{1,...,n-1\}$.

  Then the qualifying values of $b$ are the elements of $\{a,...,n-1\}$ which are divisible by 
  $$\frac{n}{\gcd(a,n)}$$

  Each such $b$ has the form 
  $$b=w{\,\cdot\,}\frac{n}{\gcd(a,n)}$$
  where $w$ is any positive integer (if any) such that
  $$a\le w{\,\cdot\,}\frac{n}{\gcd(a,n)} < n$$
  The smallest such $w$ is
  $$
  \left\lceil
  \frac{a{\,\cdot}\gcd(a,n)}{n}
  \right\rceil
  $$
  and the largest such $w$ is
  $$\gcd(a,n)-1$$
  For the given value of $a$, the number of qualifying values of $b$ is the same as the number of qualyfing values of $w$, which is just
  $$
  \gcd(a,n)
  -
  \left\lceil
  \frac{a{\,\cdot}\gcd(a,n)}{n}
  \right\rceil
  $$
  Then $g(n)$ is just the sum of the above for $1\le a\le n-1$.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer as well as your edits to the OP to make it much clearer.  I really appreciate it as I'm very new to stack exchange! This looks like it's what I was looking for.  I'll examine further :) Thanks again

Comment: Do you know if there would be a way of determining how many of the 4-tuples that f(n) counts would be of the form a*a=c*d?

Comment: You mean $a{\,\cdot\,}a=c{\,\cdot\,}d$?

Comment: yes that's what I mean

Comment: Yeah, whenever one of the sides is just an integer squared.

Comment: If $h(n)$ is the number of $4$-tuples $(a,b,c,d)$ counted by $f(n)$ such that $a,b,c,d$ are all distinct, then
$$
h(n)=
\sum_{k=1}^n
\sum_{a=1}^{k-1}
\left(
\gcd(a,k)
-
\left(
\left\lfloor
\frac{a{\,\cdot}\gcd(a,k)}{k}
\right\rfloor
+1
\right)
\right)
$$
hence $f(n)-h(n)$ is the count for the cases where either$\;a=b\;\;$or$\;\,c=d$.

Comment: thank you so much.  How exactly did you figure out g(n) and h(n) and how do they work?

Comment: I'll edit in an explanation for $f$ and $g$. The logic for $h$ is analogous.

Answer (score 2):

This is the Erdos multiplication table problem. There is a lot of literature on it. No closed-form solution, but very good asymptotics. See, for example, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31663/distinct-numbers-in-multiplication-table